# Delphi XE2 CMMouseLeave not triggered on TCustomControl

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In Delphi 5 this used to work. I have a component that descends from TCustomControl and I implement the cmmouseleave message:

```
procedure CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
```

Now if I am just moving the mouse over the control the message is triggered but if I am moving the mouse while keeping the mouse left button down, the same message is not triggered.
AFAIK I have not called the begindrag method and the dragmode is set to manual.
Any clue of what could be going on?

Comment: The mouse is captured when you press the left button. Hence the control will receive mouse move messages (WM_MOUSEMOVE), even if the mouse is outside the control. It will receive mouse leave message when the button is released. I highly doubt this is not the case with D5.

Comment: thanks yes the mouseleave is triggered only when I release the button, I am not sure but I thought it worked on D5, maybe not. Can I accept this as an answer?

Comment: You're welcome. I posted the comment as an answer.

Comment: `CM_MOUSELEAVE` was implemented differently in early VCL versions than it is in later versions. The VCL used to manually track the mouse and issue `CM_MOUSEENTER` and `CM_MOUSELEAVE` messages when needed. Now it lets the OS track the mouse via `TrackMouseEvent()` and issues `CM_MOUSELEAVE` in response to the `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mouse is captured when you press the left button. Hence the control will receive mouse move messages (`WM_MOUSEMOVE`) even if the mouse is outside the control. It will receive mouse leave message when the button is released. This should also be the case with D5.

You can exclude `csCaptureMouse` from `ControlStyle` if you don't want the mouse to be captured in response to a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`.